# Discrete scrolling in SWT Table

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

How to do a discrete (row-by-row) scrolling in SWT `Table` (JFace `TableViewer`)?

I need a `Table` to be scrolled "one unbroken row at a time", putting a full cell on top.

I use JFace `TableViewer`, but I didn't find a way to add a mouse-listener to it, so I made something like this:

```
TableViewer table = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.BORDER_DASH |SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
//some visual settings ommited here
table.getControl().addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseScrolled(MouseEvent e) {
            Table sourceControl = (Table)e.getSource();
            System.out.println(e.count);
            if(e.count >=0)
                sourceControl.setTopIndex(sourceControl.getTopIndex()-1);
            else
                sourceControl.setTopIndex(sourceControl.getTopIndex()+1);
        }
    });
```

But it turned out, that first of all if `e.count` equals to 3 or more, some rows are being missed. Secondly sometimes `setTopIndex()` not placing rows correctly.

Can it be done in more accurate way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, adding a `e.doit = false` in the `Listener` works perfectly. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.NONE);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText("Item " + i);
    }

    table.addListener(SWT.MouseWheel, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            e.doit = false;
            if (e.count >= 0)
                table.setTopIndex(table.getTopIndex() - 1);
            else
                table.setTopIndex(table.getTopIndex() + 1);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(shell.getSize().x, 300);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

The only case where the `TableItem` at the top isn't displayed completely is when you reach the end of the `Table` and the table's height isn't an exact multiple of the `TableItem`'s height.